# Change name order in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

In the bibliography, I would like to reverse the last author's name. I use biblatex with authoryear-comp style. Currently, I get either

```
    Bloggs, F., J. Doe und M. Mustermann
```

by default or

```
    Bloggs, F., Doe, J. und Mustermann, M.
```

using

```
    \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
```

However, I need it to look like this:

```
    Bloggs, F., Doe, J. und M. Mustermann
```

Is there any command I can use to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Untested, but have a look at the documentation how to get the authors, then you probably can use this: `\DeclareListFormat*{author}{\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}{last-first}{first-last}}` (replace `last-first` and `first-last` with what you've found).

Comment: Does that mean that you always need only the last name `given-family`? What if there is only one name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you always want the last name in `given-family` and all others in `family-given` - except if there is only one name, in which case you want that in `family-given` anyway - use

```
\DeclareNameFormat{family-given/given-family/last}{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{listtotal}}} or test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}}} 
    {\ifgiveninits
       {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiven}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}%
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid\namepartgiven}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid\namepartprefix}}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{name:revsdelim}}}
    {\ifgiveninits
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiven}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

  \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given/given-family/last}
```