# Biblatex family name, first name for all authors/editors except for the last author/editor

Tags: biblatex

I have to use a very specific style for my bibliography which looks like this:

> last name, first name; last name, first name & first name last name (Year^Edition): Title. In: last name, first name; last name, first name & first name last name (eds.): Booktitle. Location: Publisher, pagerange.

Additionally, for articles in journals, the volume and issue should be displayed like this: "Volume (Issue)".

That means, the following entries

```
    @incollection{birkmann_regulation_2011,
                        author = {Birkmann, Jörn},
                        title = {Regulation and Coupling of Society and Nature in the Context of Natural Hazards},
                        booktitle = {Coping with global environmental change, disasters and security: threats, challenges, vulnerabilities and risks},
                        editor = {Brauch, Hans Günter and Oswald Spring, Úrsula and Mesjasz, Czeslaw and Grin, John and Kameri-Mbote, Patricia and Chourou, Béchir and Dunai, Pál and Birkmann, Jörn},
                        date = {2011},
                        location = {Berlin, New York},                  
                        publisher = {Springer, Berghof Foundation},
                        pages = {1103--1128},                } 

               

 

    @collection{oakes_translocal_2005,
                       location = {London, New York},
                       title = {Translocal China: linkages, identities and the reimagining of space},
                     publisher = {Routledge, Taylor \& Francis Group},
                       editor = {Oakes, Tim and Schein, Louisa},
                       date = {2005},} 

   

    @incollection{teye_climate-induced_2022,
          location = {Cham},
          title = {Climate-Induced Migration in West Africa},
          pages = {79--105},
          booktitle = {Migration in West Africa},
          publisher = {Springer International Publishing},
          author = {Teye, Joseph Kofi and Nikoi, Ebenezer G. A.},
          editor = {Teye, Joseph Kofi},
          date = {2022},
          doi = {10.1007/978-3-030-97322-3_5},}


@article{sakdapolrak_migration_2016,
title = {Migration in a changing climate. Towards a translocal social resilience approach},
volume = {147},
doi = {10.12854/erde-147-6},
pages = {81--94},
number = {2},
journaltitle = {{DIE} {ERDE}},
author = {Sakdapolrak, Patrick and Naruchaikusol, Sopon and Ober, Kayly and Peth, Simon and Porst, Luise and Rockenbauch, Till and Tolo, Vera},
date = {2016},}

        @book{kuckartz_qualitative_2018,
        location = {Weinheim},
        edition = {4},
        title = {Qualitative Inhaltsanalyse: Methoden, Praxis, Computerunterstützung},
        publisher = {Beltz},
        author = {Kuckartz, Udo},
        date = {2018},
    }
```

should look like this:

> Birkmann J. (2011): Regulation and Coupling of Society and Nature in the Context of Natural Hazards. In: Brauch, H.G.; Oswald Spring, U; Mesjasz, C.; Grin, J.; Kameri-Mbote; P.; Chourou, B.; Dunai, P. & J. Birkmann (eds.): Coping with global environmental change, disasasters and securtiy: threats, challenges, vulnerabilities and risks. Berlin, New York: Springer, Berghof Foundation, 1103-1128.
>
> Kuckartz, U. (2018⁴): Qualitative Inhaltsanalyse: Methoden, Praxis, Computerunterstützung. Weinheim: Beltz.
>
> Oakes, T. & L. Schein (eds.) (2005): Translocal China: linkages, identities and the reimagining of space. London, New York: Routledge, Taylor & Francis Group
>
> Teye, J. K. & G. A. Ebenezer (2022): Climate-Induced Migration in West Africa. In: Teye, J. K. (ed.): Migration in West Africa. Cham: Springer International Publishing, 79-105. DOI: 10.1007/978-3-030-97322-3_5.
>
> Sakdapolrak, P.; Naruchaikusol, S.; Ober, K; Peth, S.; Porst, L.; Rockenbauch T. & V. Tolo (2016): Migration in a changing climate. Towards a translocal social resilience appraoch. In: DIE ERDE 147 (2), 81-94. DOI: 10.12854/erde-147-6.

[I found one solution for reversing the display of the last author](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446731/bibliography-3-authors-last-name-first-name-last-name-first-name-and-first-na), however if there is only one author, this author is displayed as first name last name.

**Edit**: [I found another related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357014/change-name-order-in-biblatex). The solution provided there (see also MWE below) works for authors. Unfortunately the editors of `@incollection` are still printed as Given-Family

Minimal Working Example including the code from the linked solution:

```
         \documentclass[]{scrartcl}
                
                \usepackage{filecontents}
    \usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
                \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
                

            @collection{oakes_translocal_2005,
               location = {London, New York},
               title = {Translocal China: linkages, identities and the reimagining of space},
             publisher = {Routledge, Taylor \& Francis Group},
               editor = {Oakes, Tim and Schein, Louisa},
               date = {2005},}

                    @incollection{teye_climate-induced_2022,
                      location = {Cham},
                      title = {Climate-Induced Migration in West Africa},
                      pages = {79--105},
                      booktitle = {Migration in West Africa},
                      publisher = {Springer International Publishing},
                      author = {Teye, Joseph Kofi and Nikoi, Ebenezer G. A.},
                      editor = {Teye, Joseph Kofi},
                      date = {2022},
                      doi = {10.1007/978-3-030-97322-3_5},}
                
                
                    @article{sakdapolrak_migration_2016,
                    title = {Migration in a changing climate. Towards a translocal social resilience approach},
                    volume = {147},
                    doi = {10.12854/erde-147-6},
                    pages = {81--94},
                    number = {2},
                    journaltitle = {{DIE} {ERDE}},
                    author = {Sakdapolrak, Patrick and Naruchaikusol, Sopon and Ober, Kayly and Peth, Simon and Porst, Luise and Rockenbauch, Till and Tolo, Vera},
                    date = {2016},}
                
                    @book{kuckartz_qualitative_2018,
                    location = {Weinheim},
                    edition = {4},
                    title = {Qualitative Inhaltsanalyse: Methoden, Praxis, Computerunterstützung},
                    publisher = {Beltz},
                    author = {Kuckartz, Udo},
                    date = {2018},
                }
                
                \end{filecontents}
                
                \usepackage[
                            backend=biber,
                            style=ext-authoryear,
                            innamebeforetitle=true,
                            sorting=nyt,
                            giveninits=true,
                            citestyle= authoryear-icomp,
                            ibidpage=true,
                            maxbibnames=99,
                            maxcitenames=2,
                            uniquelist=false,
                            isbn=false,
                            doi=true,
                            dashed=false
                            ]{biblatex}
            
            \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
                
                \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}} %Small caps for author/editor last name
                
                \DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}                 %Print title without emphasis
                \DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{#1}             %Print booktitle without emphasis
                \DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1}          %Print journaltitle without emphasis
                
                
                
                \DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist,parencite]{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space} % use semicolon to seperate authors in bibliography and citation in text
                
                \DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist,parencite]{finalnamedelim}{\space\&\space} % use & to seperate last author/editor in bibliography
                
                \DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space} % use colon to seperate (Year) and Title
                
                \DeclareDelimFormat[textcite, parencite]{postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space} % use colon to seperate Year and page in citation
                
                
                %%% Reversing only the last author to given-family %%%
               \DeclareNameFormat{family-given/given-family/last}{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{listtotal}}} or test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}}} 
    {\ifgiveninits
       {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiven}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}%
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid\namepartgiven}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid\namepartprefix}}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{name:revsdelim}}}
    {\ifgiveninits
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiven}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

  \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given/given-family/last}
                  
        
        %% Removing p. and pp. from bibliography and citation %%
        \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
          page             = {},
          pages            = {},
        } 
        
        
        %% (ed.) and (eds.) %%
        \DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
        \DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
        
        \DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
        \DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}
                
                \begin{document}
                \nocite{*}
                \printbibliography
                \end{document}
```

[image]

While the second linked solution works for the authors, and editors if the whole `@collection` is referenced, the editors are not displayed correctly for `@incollection` (see first and last entry).

**Bonus question:** How do I get the edition as a superscript after the year?

Comment: For the single author problem, have you tried wrapping the conditional test you've coded up inside another `\ifnumequal{1}{\value{listtotal}}` to handle the case of a single author?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, btw!

Comment: @WillieWong thanks for the reply! To be honest, I only copied the code from the linked question but do not fully understand it. I tried to change it a bit but it either does nothing different or I can't compile it at all. However, I found another question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357014/change-name-order-in-biblatex) where the solution is similar but different. This works now for the authors, but not the editors.

Comment: For your "bonus question" you might be interested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/560267/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/420185/35864. If that does not help, I suggest you ask a new question. This site works best when question focus on one specific aspect of a style and don't include additional/bonus requirements. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864.

Comment: @moewe thanks for sharing the link. I will have a look at it and try to adapt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there with [Change name order in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/357014/35864). You just need to set the name format `ineditor`, which prints the editors in the cases that are still missing, to `sortname`.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear-icomp,
  maxbibnames=99,
  maxcitenames=2,
  uniquelist=false,
  giveninits=true,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
  dashed=false,
  isbn=false,
  doi=true,
  ibidpage=true,
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist,parencite]{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist,parencite]{finalnamedelim}{\space\&\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[textcite, parencite]{postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareNameFormat{family-given/given-family/last}{%
  \ifboolexpr{   test {\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{listtotal}}}
              or test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}}}
    {\ifgiveninits
       {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiven}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}%
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid\namepartgiven}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid\namepartprefix}}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{name:revsdelim}}}
    {\ifgiveninits
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiven}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given/given-family/last}
\DeclareNameAlias{ineditor}{sortname}


\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{volcitepages}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{birkmann_regulation_2011,
  author    = {Birkmann, Jörn},
  title     = {Regulation and Coupling of Society and Nature
               in the Context of Natural Hazards},
  booktitle = {Coping with global environmental change, disasters and security:
               threats, challenges, vulnerabilities and risks} ,
  editor    = {Brauch, Hans Günter and Oswald Spring, Úrsula
               and Mesjasz, Czeslaw and Grin, John and Kameri-Mbote, Patricia
               and Chourou, Béchir and Dunai, Pál and Birkmann, Jörn},
  date      = {2011},
  location  = {Berlin, New York},                  
  publisher = {Springer, Berghof Foundation},
  pages     = {1103--1128},
} 
@collection{oakes_translocal_2005,
  location  = {London, New York},
  title     = {Translocal China:
               linkages, identities and the reimagining of space},
  publisher = {Routledge, Taylor \& Francis Group},
  editor    = {Oakes, Tim and Schein, Louisa},
  date      = {2005},
}
@incollection{teye_climate-induced_2022,
  location  = {Cham},
  title     = {Climate-Induced Migration in West Africa},
  pages     = {79--105},
  booktitle = {Migration in West Africa},
  publisher = {Springer International Publishing},
  author    = {Teye, Joseph Kofi and Nikoi, Ebenezer G. A.},
  editor    = {Teye, Joseph Kofi},
  date      = {2022},
  doi       = {10.1007/978-3-030-97322-3_5},
}
@article{sakdapolrak_migration_2016,
  title        = {Migration in a changing climate.
                  Towards a translocal social resilience approach},
  volume       = {147},
  doi          = {10.12854/erde-147-6},
  pages        = {81--94},
  number       = {2},
  journaltitle = {{DIE} {ERDE}},
  author       = {Sakdapolrak, Patrick and Naruchaikusol, Sopon
                  and Ober, Kayly and Peth, Simon and Porst, Luise
                  and Rockenbauch, Till and Tolo, Vera},
  date         = {2016},
}
@book{kuckartz_qualitative_2018,
  location  = {Weinheim},
  edition   = {4},
  title     = {Qualitative Inhaltsanalyse:
               Methoden, Praxis, Computerunterstützung},
  publisher = {Beltz},
  author    = {Kuckartz, Udo},
  date      = {2018},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Birkmann, J. (2011): Regulation and Coupling of Society and Nature in the Context of Natural Hazards. In: Brauch, H. G.; Oswald Spring, Ú.; Mesjasz, C.; Grin, J.; Kameri-Mbote, P.; Chourou, B.; Dunai, P. & J. Birkmann (eds.): Coping with global environmental change, disasters and security: threats, challenges, vulnerabilities and risks. Berlin, New York: Springer, Berghof Foundation, 1103–1128.]

Comment: thank you very much, this solved the problem!